# How to dockerize Slanger for a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, pusher

[Slanger](https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger) is an open source server implementation of the Pusher protocol written in Ruby.

According to the Slanger project README.md, Slanger is not designed to run inside a Rails.

> It is not designed to run inside a Rails or sinatra app

It would be well engineered to dockerize it along with a Ruby on Rails application. What would be the steps to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find below the steps in details. And for your reference, all the code is available on [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/yucigou/dockerize_rails_slanger).

#### Configure a Redis container

Slanger [depends on Redis](https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger). So first of all, you need a Redis container to run alongside.

In your docker-compose.yml, add (as an example):

```
redis:
  image: redis:4.0-alpine
```

#### Dockerize Slanger

Add a Dockerfile (e.g., Dockerfile-slanger) for Slanger

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN gem install slanger
CMD slanger --app_key $APPKEY --secret $APPSECRET -r redis://$REDIS_HOST:$REDIS_PORT/$REDIS_DB
```

Update your docker-compose.yml

```
slanger:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-slanger
  depends_on:
    - redis
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  env_file:
    - .env.slanger
```

The environment file .env.slanger looks like this:

```
APPKEY=application_key
APPSECRET=the_secret_for_the_application
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DB=Slanger
```

Also in your docker-compose.yml, add slanger to your Rails application's dependency list:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
    - db
    - slanger
  env_file:
    - .env
```

#### Use Pusher to talk to Slanger

Now you need to add the pusher gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'pusher'
```

Next you need to configure Slanger in your Rails app by adding file config/initializers/pusher.rb

```
Pusher.app_id='application_id'
Pusher.key='application_key'
Pusher.secret='the_secret_for_the_application'
Pusher.host='slanger'
Pusher.port=4567
Pusher.logger=Rails.logger
```

That's it. Now you can use Pusher in Rails to publish messages to a channel of your Slanger server via Slanger API port, and also use Pusher in JavaScript to subscribe the channel of your Slanger server via WebSocket. Please find below the example.

Rails

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def subscribe
    puts 'Subscribed'
  end

  def publish
    message = search_params.require(:message)

    Pusher.trigger('MY_CHANNEL', 'AN_EVENT', message: message)
    puts 'Published'
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.permit(:message)
  end
end
```

JavaScript

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.2/pusher.min.js"></script>

<p>Have subscribed to a Slanger channel</p>
<p>Listening via WebSocket...</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var pusher = new Pusher('application_key', {
        wsHost: "localhost",
        wsPort: "8080",
        wssPort: "8080",
        enabledTransports: ['ws', 'flash']
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('MY_CHANNEL');
    channel.bind('AN_EVENT', function(data) {
        console.log('data: ', data);
    });

    Pusher.log = function(data) {
        console.log('\t\t', data);
    };
</script>
```

#### Build and run with docker compose

Once everything is in place, you can build docker images and run your app with docker compose:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
9e3996f55e7c        helloslanger_web       "bundle exec rails..."   13 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   helloslanger_web_1
24c8b05f22a5        helloslanger_slanger   "/bin/sh -c 'slang..."   About an hour ago   Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   helloslanger_slanger_1
6baa9eec8c5a        redis:4.0-alpine       "docker-entrypoint..."   4 days ago          Up 14 seconds       6379/tcp                 helloslanger_redis_1
46bc3498a5bf        postgres               "docker-entrypoint..."   4 days ago          Up 14 seconds       5432/tcp                 helloslanger_db_1
```

#### Test

Now open the subscriber URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/message/subscribe
```

And publish a message:

```
http://localhost:3000/message/publish/Slanger%20is%20cool
```

Then in the subscriber's browser console, you'll see:

```
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"AN_EVENT","data":{"message":"Slanger is cool"},"channel":"MY_CHANNEL"}
data:  {message: "Slanger is cool"}
```

Hope it helps.

By the way, if you would like to find out how to dockerize your Rails application using docker compose, refer to [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/).